# Have IIS notify ASP.NET when last chunk of file download sent

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, download

I'm currently using this code to know if the final chunk of a file download was sent or not, and it works, but not a good design, so looking for better options:

```
    Response.ClearHeaders()
    Response.ClearContent()
    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""WebInstall.exe""")

    Response.BufferOutput = False

    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length())

    Dim bytesSent As Integer = 0

    Do While Response.IsClientConnected And (bytesSent < bytes.Length())

        Dim len As Integer
        Dim bytesLeft As Integer = bytes.Length() - bytesSent
        If bytesLeft > 80 * 1024 Then
            len = 80 * 1024
        Else
            len = bytesLeft
        End If

        Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, bytesSent, len)
        Response.OutputStream.Flush()

        bytesSent += len

    Loop

    If Response.IsClientConnected Then
        AddToWebLog("Download completed")
        NotifyAdProvider()
    Else
        AddToWebLog("Disconnected before download completed")
    End If

    Response.End()
```

The problem with the code above is that my ASP.NET code can't return to IIS until the last chunk of download is written.  Those who work with ASP.NET a lot know why this is a bad design -- it ties up one of the few available worker threads, among other reasons.

I need to know this info for logging, and also to pay people that sent me the visitor, so it is pretty important (15% of visitors don't actually download, probably due to warnings they get from browsers, anti-virus, etc, etc -- so I don't want to pay an extra 15%, and my ad providers are fine with that).

IIS has this info, because the IIS logs have a "64" for the status code if the connection was closed before complete.  So looking for a way to either have IIS call me again when the request is "done" or some other robust methods you guys might have used, maybe an API to access the IIS log or something (reading the file itself probably will not work, since it is cached and doesn't get written to right away).  I have seen some asynchronous methods for ASP.NET pages that need to do "long running tasks" but they seem very complex so I'm saving that as a last resort.

I'm using ASP.NET 3.5 and IIS 6.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_extra.html#aborted

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping for something more real-time than log parsing.  Could work if IIS fired an ASP.NET event before it adds to the log, but it doesn't appear to have that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more I read about pageasyntask, it actually doesn't look too bad. I think using BeginWrite will be the way to go.

Comment: I don't know about that method specifically, but yes, Async is the way you will want to go.